# MIPS: Why do we need the stack?

Tags: assembly, stack, mips

What is the purpose of the stack in MIPS and why do we need it? Can someone give also an example code where it would be relevant?

Comment: To implement what C calls automatic storage (local variables) efficiently when you run out of registers, or across function calls.

Comment: you don't *need* stack. But it is often most simple/efficient way of using computer memory for storage in LIFO (last in, first out) way.

Comment: [Why is memory split up into stack and heap?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8173353/995714), [What is the purpose of a stack? Why do we need it?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7875253/995714)

Comment: Why you stress MIPS? Stack is used similarly by most processors.

Comment: @LưuVĩnhPhúc: The third link (second link in the second comment) seems not to be related to the "normal" stack but to some special "stack" used in .NET calculations.

Answer (score 1):

Think of the following recursively defined C function:

```
int f(int n)
{
    if(n<3)
    {
        return n+4;
    }
    else
    {
        return f(n-1)+f(n-2);
    }
}
```

You are calling `f(20)`.

The following will happen:

Initially the return address is located in the register `$ra`.

The function calls itself with the function argument `f(19)` and `f(19)` returns. So far so good. Some register will now contain the value returned by `f(19)`.

Now the function calls itself with the argument `f(18)`.

The value returned by `f(19)` had been stored in some register. Either `f(19)` was writing the value there; in this case `f(18)` is overwriting this register because `f(19)` and `f(18)` are the same function. Or `f(20)` was writing the value there ... well `f(20)` and `f(18)` are the same function.

The register will be overwritten in any case.

So storing the value returned in a register will not work. How about storing in a global variable?

```
int intermediate;

int f(int n)
{
    ...
    intermediate = f(n-1);
    return f(n-2) + intermediate;
}
```

We will have the same problem: Calling `f(18)` will overwrite the variable `intermediate` so we cannot do the addition any more ...

... and when we want to return from the function we have the next problem: By calling `f(19)` we have overwritten `$ra` ...

Using local variables will only move the problem:

```
int f(int n)
{
    int local;
    ...
}
```

=> Where shall we store the variable `local`? In a fixed memory address (= global variable) or in a register? In both cases we have the same problem as described above.

Now we could think of the following solution:

```
int intermediate[100];

int f(int n, int level)
{
    ...
    intermediate[level] = f(n-1, level+1);
    intermediate[level] += f(n-2, level+1);
    ...
}
```

So `f(20)` will use `intermediate[0]`, the functions being called from `f(20)` use `intermediate[1]` and the functions being called from that functions use `intermediate[2]` and so on...

**Exactly** this is the concept of a "stack"!

However you don't have to implement this yourself but it is already pre-defined that the register `$sp` points to the memory you can use (`level` in the example).